# Port/Automate the process of theme development to modules development

Tags: theming

Thank you for taking time to give me guidance and advice for this ^^.

So we have a Drupal starter theme using: scss, es6, webpack, grunt, linting, .editorconfig, bower and so one.

All of this allows the team to understand the code of each other and keep everything organised.

I was wondering if there was a possibility to do the same for modules (it is possible actually). My question is how we can manage all of this stuff.

If we place these files inside each custom module we have, it will be hard to maintain. Is there an approach to create for example a grunt file for each module that inherit another configuration (core one - only one), and let's imagine having one core module which compile everything when needed - keeping in mind that we may need for each page to load a specific/different js/css.

Can we achieve something like that ?